# set mesh position at intersectionPoint from impl.rayIntersect()

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

the intersection point from the following method returns a vector that sets the position of the mesh in a different location from where I clicked

`
const intersects =
viewer.impl.rayIntersect(
rayCaster.ray,
true
);

```
  const intPt = intersects.intersectPoint;

  sphereMesh.position.set(
    intPt.x,
    intPt.y,
    intPt.z
  );
  viewer.overlays.addMesh(
    sphereMesh,
    "viewer-scene"
  );
```

`

I tried using viewer.resize() method and even setting the global offset to 0,0,0 but it doesnt fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the ray you're using is setup correctly. It might be pointing in a different direction, hitting different geometry, and therefore returning different intersection points.

I've tried the following code snippet, and the spheres are positioned correctly:

```js
const sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5.0, 8, 8);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x336699 });

NOP_VIEWER.overlays.addScene('spheres');
NOP_VIEWER.container.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    const { clientX, clientY } = ev;
    const rect = NOP_VIEWER.container.getBoundingClientRect();
    const result = NOP_VIEWER.hitTest(clientX - rect.left, clientY - rect.top);
    if (result) {
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, material);
        mesh.position.copy(result.point);
        NOP_VIEWER.overlays.addMesh(mesh, 'spheres');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying me Petr
I used the common three js raycaster setup:

`
const rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2(
        (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 -
          1,
        -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) *
          2 +
          1
      );
      rayCaster.setFromCamera(
        mouse,
        viewer.getCamera().perspectiveCamera
      );
      const intersects =
        viewer.impl.rayIntersect(
          rayCaster.ray,
          true
        );
      const intPt = intersects.intersectPoint;
`
Somehow isn't working

Comment: Then I tried your approach using the hitTest() command from the viewer and works perfectly. What is wrong with the custom three js workflow?

Comment: It might be the way you compute the 2D coords for the ray (`(event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1`). This may not provide the correct values if the viewer is hosted in a certain HTML element on the page (not covering the entire page).

Comment: I meant three js use those default values though. I guess I will stick to the forge worflow